# Coroutines with a growing stack in C

Tags: c, linux, mmap, coroutine

I want to use coroutines in C (Linux), but I don't want to waste lots of space for each one. I'm wondering about allocating the space for the stack with `mmap()` given `MAP_GROWSDOWN`, but I read somewhere that it was broken, do you know any more about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I don't want to waste lots of space for each one

Don't worry about it. Your coroutine can have a large stack but it will not cause any performance or resource problems unless the stack is actually *used*. The logical pages of memory will not be assigned physical pages until that point.  And if it is used, well you needed it then didn't you?

Just use a decent sized stack and have done with it.

Comment: So what your saying is that I should allocate a large `mmap` mapping and that the memory won't be used until it is physically touched?

Comment: A word of caution though: you can exhaust your virtual address space even if you don't use the memory.

Comment: @Sylvain, I realise this; thankfully, I'm targeting 64bit architectures.